# How do you place text along the bottom of an image?

Tags: html, css

How do you place text above an image, such that it runs across the bottom of the image.

i.e.

```
<div class="i_have_an_image">
<h2>I appear on top of the image, but aligned along the bottom</h2>
</div>
```

I am struggling to work it out, to see what I mean, The following web site, has a great example of this. I've seen it before on sites, heres an example snapshot of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: the bottom piece is a div with low opacity

Comment: @Paulie_D Overlay along __bottom__ of image.

Comment: @NitinDhomse Yes it is.

Comment: @Paulie_D If there was an answer on stack overflow I could find, I would not have needed to post the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the image in an `inline-block` div which has `position:relative`.

Position the `h2` absolutely with `bottom:0` and `width:100%` and the height of the `h2` will adjust automatically to the content of the positioned element.

```css
.i_have_an_image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.i_have_an_image img {
  display: block;
}
.i_have_an_image h2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="i_have_an_image">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="">
  <h2>I appear on top of the image, but aligned along the bottom</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this:
I added only the "wrap" div

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 300px;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -78px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #222222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="i_have_an_image">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://www.theage.com.au/content/dam/images/g/p/o/1/v/l/image.related.homepagePortrait.300x370.gpnu1x.2f8s9.png/1466499504473.jpg" alt="Angelika Graswald in court with her lawyers. " width="300" height="370">
    <h2>I appear on top of the image, but aligned along the bottom</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.i_have_an_image{
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
h2{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color:#fff;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
     
     
<div class="i_have_an_image">

<img src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/32854-image/First-samples-from-Sonys-new-13MP-stacked-camera-sensor-capable-of-HDR-video-show-up.jpg">
  <h2>I appear on top of the image, but aligned along the bottom</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.butFrame {
  width: 32%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.butFrame .butHeading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="butFrame">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/380/210?random">
  <div class="butHeading">Heading</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n0aLts9w/

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution of image with heading and sub heading.** (As per your given image)

**Demo Here**

```css
.i_have_an_image{
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/McIDx6g.jpg);
  background: url((http://i.imgur.com/McIDx6g.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
.title_wrap{ 
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.title_wrap h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.title_wrap h6 { 
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="i_have_an_image">
  <div class="title_wrap">
    <h2>Heading goes here</h2>
    <h6>I appear on top of the image, but aligned along the bottom</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've been doing it recently. It's using the new html5 tag figcaption

It doesn't matter how big the image is or what you put in the figcaption it should just work.

```css
figure.overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
figure.overlay figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: calc(100%-10px);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="overlay">
  <img src="http://www.dogbreedinfo.com/images/germanshepherdface.jpg">
  <figcaption>
    <h3>
        'Some header of some sort!'
      </h3> Words that make up a sentance! Or maybe 2 sentances.
    <br />
    <br />Even with a new line
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ho you can do it with flexbox simply like this:

```css
.imageWrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

.textAboveImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 200;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="textAboveImage">I'm text</div>
</div>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:
I added only the "wrap" div

HTML:

```
<div class="i_have_an_image">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://www.theage.com.au/content/dam/images/g/p/o/1/v/l/image.related.homepagePortrait.300x370.gpnu1x.2f8s9.png/1466499504473.jpg" alt="Angelika Graswald in court with her lawyers. " width="300" height="370">
    <h2>I appear on top of the image, but aligned along the bottom</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .wrap {
    max-width: 300px;
}
h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: -78px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: #222222;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `top: -78px` force a certain height, and then cause a problem if the heading wraps into two lines? I think there is a solution that allows you to use `vertical-align: bottom` but I've not managed to work it out yet.